# Instantiate a static variable to be called from another module in python

Tags: python, variables, module, static, attributeerror

I have a peculiar problem.

I currently have a script `script1` which generates multiple experiments, each of which is run with `script2`. In order to run `script1`, as well as all of `script2`s, I need to do an API call (to WandB), and fetch some data. Thus, I have decided to create a seperate class which will store the data from this API call, so that I can successfully run `script1`, and then I can successfully also fetch the data without re-calling the API fetch throughout all of `script2`s. Additionally, `script2` has its own argument which I typically pass in through a command line. How can I incorporate this new functionality, whilst still being able to call `script2` from terminal?

My problem is, however, that python is not letting me keep the instantiated static variables, and instead is saying there is no such attribute. I'm wondering if there is a solution to this problem without having to do excessive API calls each time I run each individual `script2`.

A very bare construction of the problem is as follows:

`script1.py`:

```
from helper import Helper

import os

print("Running script1")
# This is mimicking our API call
number_from_api = 5
# Record the fetched value as a static variable in a class
hlpr = Helper(number_from_api)
num = Helper.number
print(f"The num fetched is {num}")
for _ in range(num):
    os.system("python3 script2.py")
```

`script2.py`:

```
from helper import Helper

print("Running script2!")
result = Helper.number + 2
print(f"New result is {result}")
```

`helper.py`:

```
class Helper():

    def __init__(self, number):
        print("Initializing Helper Class")
        Helper.number = number
```

Running `python3 script1.py` returns the error:

```
File "C:\my_path\script2.py", line
4, in <module>
    result = Helper.number + 2
AttributeError: type object 'Helper' has no attribute 'number'
```

If anyone has a solution to this exact problem, or perhaps knows a workaround to avoid, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. It has valuable debugging information.

Comment: You are running several processes through OS calls but only instantiating Helper in one process so script2 has no access to the instantiated number.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the error you are facing, you need to change your Helper class like this. Because you didn't instantiate the Helper class in script2.

```
class Helper:
    number = 0 # it is required!

    def __init__(self, number):
        print("Initializing Helper Class")
        Helper.number = number
```

Also, I would suggest you use Redis or something like that to store/read shared data between multiple processes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue, `number` will always have a value of 0 when trying to be fetched.

Comment: Yes, take a look at this lib and try to use it for your storage, your current code doesn't make sense, https://github.com/redis/redis-py
It's a key-value store that you can use to share data between multiple processes like your scenario.